# Generate lat long for position within a set of boundries

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

We are using Google maps API V3 and we have a set of boundries (currently in a KML file) which are not square (let's use the shape of England as an example) and I need to generate a random latitude and longitude from within the boundry when a user completes an action.

Is there any clever way of doing this in javascript/jQuery or a javascript library that would do this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this I think Dave.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure.html

With this
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/country_explorer/country_explorer.html

Comment: This also could be useful  http://www.paulmcilwaine.com/api/google-maps-detecting-markers-in-a-particular-boundary http://www.paulmcilwaine.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/map.html it uses a circle

Answer (score 0):

No personal experience, but [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)?  It can determine if a point intersects with other geometry [OpenLayers.Geometry.Point](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.intersects) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to get a random point in a non-rectangular shape is:

```
 1) Compute the bounding rectangle (cheap)
 2) Generate a point in the bounding rectangle (cheap)
 3) Check if that point is inside your shape (expensive)
    3.1) If it is, return the point
    3.2) If it is not, go back to (2)
```

Depending on the complexity of the shape, this may be enough. You could use other generation shapes (a circle, or some other simplified shape) if they are known to be better approximations of your source shape,

OpenLayers indeed has geometry primitives such that you can implement this in a few lines.